# Can't open Email Attachments file in Microsoft office

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-office-2007

I can't open my email attached file in MS Word for editing.

How can I disable protect view in Microsoft Office 2007 while opening Email attachments or downloaded files?

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I disable protect view in Microsoft Office 2007?

You need to change the settings in the Trust Centre. See below for instructions.

---

#### Solution to Microsoft Outlook 2007 or 2010 not opening Word or Excel Attachments

> To solve the problem of opening Word (and Excel) documents in
>   Microsoft Outlook:
>
> 1. Close Microsoft Outlook
> 2. Open Microsoft Word
> 3. Click File (or little Office orb for 2007 version) in the upper left hand corner of screen
> 4. Click Options
> 5. Click Trust Center
> 6. Click Trust Center Settings
> 7. Click Protected View
> 8. Uncheck the following boxes:
>
>    - Enable protected view for files originating from the internet
>    - Enable protected view for files located in potentially unsafe locations
>    - Enable protected view for outlook attachments
>
>    [image]
> 9. Click OK 10    Click OK again
>      Close Word
>      Open Microsoft Outlook and try your attachments again

Source [Solution to Microsoft Outlook 2007 or 2010 not opening Word or Excel Attachments](http://helpmerick.com/solution-to-microsoft-outlook-2007-or-2010-not-opening-word-or-excel-attachments.htm)

Comment: If you can't open ANY attachment in Outlook, could be because no default application is set for the type of document you want to open. Go to Settings, Applications, Default applications, and check if there's, say, a PDF reader designated as default. If there's just a grey rectangle with a "+" sign, click on the grey area and select an application from the drop-down/pop-up menu, and that should be it.